# Where does Windows 7 Photo Viewer Store User Specific Data / Settings?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printing, windows-photo-viewer

I've got a situation where I've got a printer driver (which I'm developing), which works fine in Windows Photo Viewer for all users on my machine... apart from me!

I'm thinking that during development, I must have inadvertently toggled a Photo Viewer setting or cached something for my particular user profile, as when I now go to print using my profile, it fails to start spooling. I think internally Windows Photo Viewer is failing the print.

I've noticed that when I've changed the GDP file for the printer and re-installed, the new GPD settings don't seem to be reflected in the print gui of Photo Viewer, maybe like it's been cached.

So, does anyone know where the user specific data for Windows 7 Photo Viewer is stored?

Thanks!

Andy.

Answer (score 1):

Found the cause of my issue. For each printer, Windows Photo Viewer seems to store the printer drivers Print Ticket and Print Capabilities document. As during development I was changing both of these, I'm guessing one of both of the must have become corrupt or otherwise become something photo viewer wasn't expecting for my printer.

The registry entries aren't removed when the printer is removed so you have to remove them manually. You can find them here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\PhotoPrintingWizard\[Print name]
```

Hope this helps someone! :)

Andy